# passing data to a classe and in the same time open a another screen FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

on Tap i want to open show_data() as screen and in the same Time send 'entries[index]'as city  to FinalData(),

**entries is a list of city's**

main.dart

```
final List<String> entries = <String>[
    'Casablanca',
    'Agadir',
    'Marrakech',
    'Tanger'
  ];
  final List<String> City = <String>[
    'assets/images/casablanca.png',
    'assets/images/Agadir.PNG',
    'assets/images/marrakech.PNG',
    'assets/images/Tanger.PNG'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Meteo Maroc'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.separated(
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: entries.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    const show_data(),
                      
                ),
               
              ),
              
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
                height: 400,

                // child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(City[index]),
                    Text(
                      entries[index],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          height: 2,
                          fontSize: 26,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
```

i want to receive entries[index] from main.dart as city in FinalData.dart to get the weather of this city .

FinalData.dart

```
class FinalData with ChangeNotifier{
  String city;
  FinalData({required this.city});
  
 List <Met_data> MetData=[];
Future<List<Met_data>?> getDataMet() async {
    var url = Uri.https('api.openweathermap.org', '/data/2.5/weather',
        {'q': city, 'units': 'metric', 'appid': apiKey});
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse =
          convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
          
          MetData.add(Met_data.fromJson(jsonResponse));
          
          return MetData;
    } else {
     print(response.statusCode);
    }
    
    return null;
    // ignore: dead_code
    notifyListeners();
  
  }
```

and display the weather in show_met.dart

show_met.dart

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<FinalData>(context).getDataMet(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.data != null) // check for null
          {
            List<Met_data>? data = snapshot.data as List<Met_data>;

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            }
            if (snapshot.data != Null) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      data[index].temp.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        fontSize: 36,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } 
          }
          return const Center(child: Text('Load ok'),);
        }
        
      ),
```

Comment: could you include full code?

Comment: done ,  i include it

Comment: where do you call show_met?

Comment: after clicking on GestureDetector in main.dart i want to open screen 'show_met.dart ' and passing data to FinalData.dart in the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass city like this:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    const show_met(entries[index]),
                      
                ),
               
              ),
```

then change your show_met.dart to accept that city:

```
class show_met extends StatefulWidget {
  const show_met({Key? key, required this.city}) : super(key: key);
  final String city;
  @override
  State<show_met> createState() => _show_metState();
}
```

then change your `getDataMet` in `FinalData`:

```
Future<List<Met_data>?> getDataMet(String city) async {
    var url = Uri.https('api.openweathermap.org', '/data/2.5/weather',
        {'q': city, 'units': 'metric', 'appid': apiKey});
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse =
          convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
          
          MetData.add(Met_data.fromJson(jsonResponse));
          
          return MetData;
    } else {
     print(response.statusCode);
    }
    
    return null;
    // ignore: dead_code
    notifyListeners();
  
  }
```

then pass city to getDataMet in show_met class:

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<FinalData>(context).getDataMet(widget.city),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          ...
        }
)
```